# Find a record in dbset without a primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `Student` table wherein I find a record with primary key `UserID` using Find

```
        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var newid = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserID == currentUserId);

        if (newid == null)
        {
            newid = db.Students.Create();
            newid.UserID = currentUserId;
            db.Students.Add(newid);

        }

        Student student = db.Students.Find(newid.UserID);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

My question is how do I find a record but cannot use his primary key? In my case my `IndividualInventoryRecord` has primary key `RecordID`. I want to find a record from this table using FK `UserID`

I have tried this but `inventory` returns null

```
var userInv = db.IndividualInventoryRecords.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserID == currentUserId);

        if (userInv == null)
        {
            userInv = db.IndividualInventoryRecords.Create();
            userInv.UserID = currentUserId;
            db.IndividualInventoryRecords.Add(userInv);
        }

        IndividualInventoryRecord inventory = db.IndividualInventoryRecords.FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserID == currentUserId);

        if (inventory == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

I also tried using SingleOrDefault()

Comment: If `.FirstOrDefault()` returns null then that means no matching records were found.  It's working successfully, you're just getting zero results from the data.  (Contrast to using `.Where()` which would successfully return an empty collection.)

Comment: Yes but isn't it supposed to have a record since I added the currentUserId to the table?

Comment: It's kind of strange that you're looking for the exact object that you just added.  You already have that object, in the `userInv` variable.  Maybe you just need to call `.SaveChanges()` first?  That doesn't make it any less strange, but may make it work.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. I called `.SaveChanges()`. I don't get it though, in my previous codes I didn't have to call `.SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `Find` method is the only method which takes the local cache into account. All standard `Queryable` methods are translated to SQL and executed in database, hence return only existing database table records.

However it's not that hard to write your own custom extension method similar to `Find` but with predicate expression:

```
public static partial class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static T FindFirst<T>(this DbSet<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        where T : class
    {
        return source.Local.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(predicate) ?? source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

and use it instead of `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var inventory = db.IndividualInventoryRecords.FindFirst(e => e.UserID == currentUserId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, you are not saving to database the `userInv` instance. Just save it;

```
    if (userInv == null)
    {
        userInv = db.IndividualInventoryRecords.Create();
        userInv.UserID = currentUserId;
        db.IndividualInventoryRecords.Add(userInv);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    IndividualInventoryRecord inventory = db.IndividualInventoryRecords.FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserID == currentUserId);
```